# make delay in canActivate till IP address data is fetched

Tags: angular, angular-router, canactivate, angular-guards

I'm making a guard for my angular application where all users should be redirected to maintenance page except for certain IPs. I'm getting the client IP address using third party APIs like `http://api.ipify.org/?format=json`. The **PROBLEM** I'm facing is that the canActivate guard gets executed before the IP API sends in the response, thus always returning false and then the response gets loaded.

**canActivate Function**

```
  canActivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.globalService.getCanactivateStatus()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(["/en/maintainance"]);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**Service**

```
  getUserIp() {
    this.http.get<{ ip: string }>("http://api.ipify.org/?format=json").subscribe((data) => {
      this.clientIP = data.ip;
    });
  }

  getCanactivateStatus() {
    this.getUserIp()
      if (this.maintainance_status) {
        if (this.IpArray.indexOf(this.clientIP) !== -1) { //this.clientIP waits for response while canactivated gets executed
          return true
         }
      } else return true 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try returning an observable instead of true / false and filter it so it will fire if conditions are met like:

```
return this.globalService.getCanactivateStatus()
        .pipe(
          filter((status) => !!status),
          take(1)
        )
```

You should implement the return logic at getCanactivateStatus() to get this work

Comment: can you explain a bit more